# How to solve SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to solve this error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

i was sending some data from and to ajax and php.

here is my ajax code:

```
flag = 111;
var dt = $(this).serializeArray();
dt.push({
  name: 'flag',
  value: flag
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'emp.php',
  type: "post",
  async: true,
  data: dt,
  dataType: 'html',
  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  success: function(data) {
    var x = JSON.parse(data); //THIS Line shows error!!
    alert(x);
    $('#name').val(x.ename);
    $('#designation').val(x.designation);
    $('#department').val(x.department);
    $('#sd').val(x.secdivision);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

here is my php:

```
$empid = (isset($_POST['employeeid'])) ? $_POST['employeeid'] : 'NOT';
$flag  = (isset($_POST['flag'])) ? $_POST['flag'] : 0;
if($flag == 111){
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, " begin   
                       :result :=  PKG_PAYROLL.get_emp_by_id('<employee_id>$empid/employee_id>');  
                       end;" ); 

    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':result',$ru, 5000);   
    $output = oci_execute($stid);
    $ru = new SimpleXMLElement($ru);    
    $json = json_encode($ru, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    $jsonarray = json_decode($json ,true);  
    $jsn = $jsonarray['employee'];

    $array = array('employee' =>   $jsn['EMPID'],
                       'ename' => $jsn['ENAME'],
                       'designation' => $jsn['DESIGNATION'], 
                       'department'=>  $jsn['DEPARTMENT'],
                       'secdivision'=>  $jsn['SECDIVISION']);                      
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Updates: 
Here is a sample of response data i got in console after `echo json_encode($array);`

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding
='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f
; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: employee in C:\wamp\www\Payroll\emp.php
 on line <i>24</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align
='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left'
 bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0002</td><td bgcolor
='#eeeeec' align='right'>247040</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\Payroll
\emp.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\emp.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"employee":"FMCSC00015","ename":"Tom","designation":"Teacher","department":"English","secdivision":"Academic"
}
```

> parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1
>   column 1 of the JSON data

I am confuse about the main reason of this error, because i already did same type of coding with json earlier. I checked that php is working fine.

Comment: Have a look at Network tab is see what is returned for the array before you encode the array as a json

Comment: Thanks @Won Jun Bae . Which file to check for  network tab php or ajax? thanks

Comment: what `if($flag != 111){`? or on some error?

Comment: you are returning json from server and parsing "HTML" dataType in client side .

Comment: you can use Inspector on Chrome

Comment: I would say you have a PHP error ( Notice: Undefined index: employee in C:\wamp\www\Payroll\emp.php on line ..) therefore you get HTML code instead JSON

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are returning `JSON` from server and parsing `HTML` dataType in client side. So, in your code change your datatype:

```
dataType: 'html'
```

to

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Drudge. on which file to do that php or html ?

Comment: Thanks @Drudge.i change the datatype to json but , i still got parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

Comment: can you print the array before encoding it to json and post it here ??

Comment: Thanks @Drudge. i posted sample response array.please help.

Comment: seriously ?? It is html man . JSON parser will only parse json data . You are trying to parse html with json  parser . Look http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/  what the json parser actually do .

Comment: i even don't know what you actually trying to do .

Comment: Thanks @Drudge. Now i got it correct.As a beginner now i understand your explanation.thanks

Comment: my pleasure buddy .  please accept the answer so that it will be helpful to others also .

Comment: Thanks @Drudge.sure i will.So for understanding purpose i want ask that, i was sending 'json' encoded data from php to ajax that accept `html` data type.So that was the error am i correct? thanks

Comment: you were sending html data from php but parsing json in your ajax call . Json only parse json data .

Answer (score 1):

****If your response is in HTML format, but response contains json data . Then you have occured this error(' JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'). To avoid this error you have use this code written  below:****

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'emp.php',
       type: "post",
       async: true,
       data: dt,
       dataType: 'html',
       contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
       success: function(data) {
       try {
         var x = JSON.parse(data);
       } catch (e) {
           return false;
       }
         //JSON.parse(data) THIS Line shows error!!
       alert(x);
       $('#name').val(x.ename);
       $('#designation').val(x.designation);
       $('#department').val(x.department);
       $('#sd').val(x.secdivision);
      },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

If you response from PHP in simple json format then you have use this code.But in this case your response from PHP file is only json format.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'emp.php',
   type: "post",
   async: true,
   data: dt,
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   success: function(data) {
   $('#name').val(data.ename);
   $('#designation').val(data.designation);
   $('#department').val(data.department);
   $('#sd').val(data.secdivision);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```